# nest ng-view inside a form

Tags: angularjs

given the controller

```
function ctl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.postForm = function() {
    console.log("submitting form")
  }
}
```

and the view

```
  <form name="pform" ng-show="!error.Show">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <button type='button' value='Save' ng-click="postForm()" />
  </form>
```

The controller method `postForm` doesn't get called, however, if i move the form tag into the view the method is called.  Is there a reason that this doesn't work as I expect it to?  Is there another way to accomplish the goal of sharing the form controls across different views?

**Update**

my module and routeProvider are configured like this:

```
angular.module("profilemodule", [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/info", { templateUrl: '/partials/profile/info.html', controller: ProfileController })
        .when("/user", { templateUrl: '/partials/profile/user.html', controller: ProfileController })
        .when("/introduction", { templateUrl: '/partials/profile/editor.html', controller: ProfileController })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/info' });
}]).run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
})
```

and the page includes some nav elements which are set based on the location service like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset2 span10">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active: location.$$path.substring(0, '/info'.length) == '/info'}"><a href="#/info" >Information</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: location.$$path.substring(0, '/user'.length) == '/user'}"><a href="#/user" >User</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: location.$$path.substring(0, '/intro'.length) == '/intro'}"><a href="#/intro" >Introduction</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<form name="pform" method="POST" ng-show="!error.Show">
   <div ng-view></div>
   <button type='button' value='Save' ng-click="postForm()" />
</form>
```

the `ng-class` statements works perfectly, is it because I've set the `location` property of `$scope` in the module's `run` method?

thanks,

jason

Comment: Is your controller (ctl) defined in the ngView's $routeProvider? If so, it is out of its scope. Try to add a new controller on your form tag (e.g. ng-controller="formCtrl") and define the postForm function there.

Comment: it is, please take a look at my updated question, because I am using other properties in that controller on the same page that contains the form and it is working.

Comment: The ng-class works because you have set the location on the $rootScope - every child scope inherits from the root so has access to its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-view` with routing creates a new scope with the controller, and you can't reach a child scope. Your submit action lies in the parent scope and the form data lies in the child scope (created by `ng-view`).

If you want to use common form controls, you can use `ng-include`, this directive gets template it and renders that in the **current scope**.

Move your form controls to a new template, then include them in all of your forms.

API reference:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude